# Rails 3 - Moving from Development to Production - Public Assets 404

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, development-environment, production-environment

I migrated a Rails 2.2.2 application to Rails 3.1.

In development mode: `/var/www/project_dir# thin start --ssl` 
all the assets are found and served beautifully.

When I run in production mode: `/var/www/project_dir# thin start --ssl -e production`
all of the asset requests (JS,CSS and images) return a 404.

The paths in development and production mode are
identical.

[image]

I have come to the point where I have exhausted all of my debugging ideas and have no ideas why when in production mode, none of the assets can be found.

I did try migrating over to asset pipeline but that caused more problems that I don't think I can solve right now so I need to solve this with asset pipeline off.

Any and all ideas are welcome and THANKS!

**Details**
Web Server: Thin 1.5.0
Asset Pipleine: Off
Asset Directories:
/var/www/project_dir/public/images
/var/www/project_dir/public/javascripts
/var/www/project_dir/public/stylesheets

**Generated Asset Paths (Development Mode)**

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1366806358" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.js?1366806358" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.alerts.js?1366806358" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1366806357" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery-ui.css?1361279500" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery.alerts.css?1361279500" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/default.css?1361279499" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Generated Asset Paths (Production Mode)**

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1366806358" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.js?1366806358" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.alerts.js?1366806358" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1366806357" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery-ui.css?1361279500" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery.alerts.css?1361279500" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/default.css?1361279499" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Did you compile your assets? `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: @Christian No, I am not using asset pipeline - That's what that is right?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. What URL does it access for that file in the development environment?

Comment: @ChristianVarga  <link href="/stylesheets/default.css?1361279499" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 8):

Apache would do this automagically for you but with Thin, you need to do the following:

In `/config/environments/production.rb`

Set this directive to true:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

That will enable production mode to read assets from the `/public` folder

Comment: In Rails 5.0, it seemed to have changed to `config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?`